# string validation in std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I am working on a code where I need to validate a `std::vector` filled with multiple `std::string` objects. The logic is that I need to check if all of the objects are valid or not. If yes then display a message saying that input vector is valid, error otherwise. Here is what I have so far.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<numeric>
#include<boost/foreach.hpp>

short multiply(short s1,short s2)
{
    return s1*s2;
}
bool validate(const std::vector<std::string> &in)
{
    std::vector<short>check(in.size(),0);
    auto checkitr = check.begin();

    BOOST_FOREACH(std::string str,in)
    {
        for(auto itr = str.begin(); itr != str.end(); ++itr)
        {
            if(*itr == 'c')
            {
                *checkitr = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        ++checkitr;
    }
    short product = std::accumulate(check.begin(),check.end(),1,multiply);

    return ( (product) ? true : false );
}

int main()
{
    std::string s1("abcd");
    std::string s2("lncd");
    std::vector<std::string>iVec;

    iVec.push_back(s1);
    iVec.push_back(s2);

    bool isValid = validate(iVec);

    if(isValid){
        std::cout<<"This Vector is valid   "<<std::endl;    
    }
    else
    {   
        std::cout<<"This is an invalid vector  "<<std::endl;        
    }

    iVec.push_back(std::string("ghkd"));

    isValid = validate(iVec);

    if(isValid){
        std::cout<<"This Vector is valid  "<<std::endl;

    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"This is an invalid vector  "<<std::endl;
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

This runs fine and gives me the result that I need.My question is,
Is there any other better/performance efficient approach in standard algorithm or boost library that I can use instead of my current approach?

Comment: Note: `BOOST_FOREACH` can likely be replaced with range-based for loop: `for(std::string str : in)`, same with the loop over characters of the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would have been nice to include a description of what the validation algorithm should validate, but I suppose the source is self-documenting. To find out whether a vector of strings contains only strings that contain a `c`, I'd use

```
#include <algorithm> // for std::none_of
#include <iterator>  // for std::begin, std::end

bool validate(const std::vector<std::string> &in)
{
  return std::none_of(std::begin(in),
                      std::end  (in),
                      [](std::string const &s) {
                        return s.find('c') == std::string::npos;
                      });
}
```

`std::none_of` checks if no element in a range satisfies a condition, and the `[](std::string const &s) { ... }` is a lambda expression that describes the condition `std::none_of` is supposed to use. Put together, this checks whether there is a string that doesn't contain a `c` in the vector, returns  `true` if there wasn't and `false` if there was.

The main runtime advantage over your code of this is that it stops checking as soon as it finds a string that doesn't contain a `c`; other than that, it is mostly shorter (unless the implementation of `std::string::find` contains clever optimizations, which is not impossible).

**Side note:** It would be possible to leave out many of the `std::` in that code because of [argument-dependent name lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup). I left some out in the original code but put them back in 
after @BoBTFish commented on it to avoid confusion; I tend to leave them out for `begin` and `end` because I'm used to doing it. This is because of a (somewhat) useful trick in the context of templates that has no real bearing on the above function, but here it is (if you're interested):

If you want this validation routine to work for more than vectors, you could write

```
template<typename Container>
bool validate(Container &&in)
{
  using std::begin;
  using std::end;

  return std::none_of(begin(std::forward<Container>(in)),
                      end  (std::forward<Container>(in)),
                      [](std::string const &s) {
                        return s.find('c') == std::string::npos;
                      });
}
```

This is adapted from a similar technique for `std::swap` described in Effective C++ by Scott Meyers; the useful thing about it is that if there are fitting implementations of `begin(...)` and `end(...)` in the namespace where the type to which `Container` refers is defined, they are preferred over `std::begin` and `std::end` -- which is good because if they exist, it is sane to assume that they provide a better fit.

(Granted that `std::begin` and `std::end`'s default behavior of using the `.begin()` and `.end()` member functions makes such implementations of `begin` and `end` mostly unnecessary, but I have seen stranger things in real-life code.)

EDIT: I didn't think of `std::none_of` right away; the original solution used `std::find_if`. `std::find_if` also works, of course, but `std::none_of` is rather obviously a better fit.

Comment: It might be beneficial to explain your code a bit more. Also, why use `std::` in most places but not on `begin` and `end`? (And British `const` for `validate` but continental `const` for the lambda?)

Comment: @BobTFish I'm used to doing that for `begin` and `end` to facilitate ADL in function templates (similar to the `swap` trick). You're right that it's not useful in functions. See the edit for my reasoning, if you're interested in corner-case handling.